# Does hashtable allow duplicate values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashtable

Let's say I have a hash table arr[1..n], a set of keys k1,k2,k3(m no. of keys) etc.. and hash function h(k)

h(k) takes input k and gives output i as an index to arr[i].

Now in linear probing concept of hashing, let's consider the scenarios.

```
1> let k1=101 and h(k)=i=5, then k1(101) is stored in arr[5]

2> let k2=102 and h(k)=i=6 then k1(102) is stored in arr[6]

3>Now again k3=101 and h(k)=i=5 then by linear probing it will go one
step ahead(i=i+1) and check a[i](a[6]) is free or not, since a[6] is not free 
so we repeat again (i=i+1) and check a[i](a[7]) is free or not, since a[7] is free
so k3(101) is again inserted at arr[7].
```

Now arr[5] and arr[7] are possible duplicates, they belong to the same key.

Does hashtable allow duplicates? Is my understanding correct.

Please verify me if I am wrong

Comment: This question is going to depend heavily on the hash table itself, since both are possible. For example, `std::unordered_map` doesn't allow duplicates, while `std::unordered_multimap` does allow duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ there are two hash containers that allow duplicates. They are `std::unordered_multiset` and `std::unordered_multimap`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from your question that you're implementing a hash table. It's up to you whether you allow multiple values for a single key. Note that doing so will make the table a little more complex to use, since you'll need to provide access to multiple values for a key.

To disallow duplicates, in step 3 in your example you would compare the key with the key in slot 5, find that they match and then either overwrite the entry or reject the incoming entry (your design decision).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a more complex discussion

1. Hash pairs can have the same key(hash function result) without having the same value, this can work if the hash is implemented to solve collisions(Usually done by adding a list, similar to what you ve been saying. Instead of an element, you have a list, you need some aditional logic to figure out which element to take.
2. Hash table implementations I know of do not allow duplicates as it would be rather out of purpse. Why would you store an element twice since you can access the same element an infinite number of times.

Comment: Your second point is misleading; OP is talking about equal *keys* and not necessarily equal *values*.

Answer (score 0):

There're a lot of different hashtable implementations.

For example, Microsoft's CAtlMap template class uses the approach called "[Separate chaining with linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists)" - i.e. the buckets are completely independent, and each bucket can contain more then a single record.

STL uses list as well. They just put all the elements in one single list ordered by the index, and in the array they hold 2 iterators pointing to the first and last element of the bucket.